# Is an iPhone still carrier activated after factory reset?

Tags: ios, restore

If I go through the process of erasing all content and settings (performing a factor reset), is the phone still activated/connected through my carrier? That is, can I perform a factory reset and then immediately make a phone call (or send a text message)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the factory reset deletes all contents and restores your phone to its newly-bought condition but other than that, you can still call/text whoever you like.